# Дергается вертикальный скролл при обновлении времени

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Как это поправить? добавлял фиксированную ширину, высоту, overflow: hidden. Ничего не помогло

```
import React from 'react';


export default class Time extends React.Component {
    state = {
      curTime: new Date()
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        this.update = setInterval(() => {
            this.setState({ curTime: new Date() });
        }, 1 * 1000); // every 1 seconds
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        clearInterval(this.update);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="header_clock">
                    {this.state.curTime.toLocaleTimeString()}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Приведите пожалуйста полный код с воспроизводимой проблемой. Вот код с ограниченными размерами, ничего не дергается:

```js
class Time extends React.Component {
    state = {
      curTime: new Date()
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        this.update = setInterval(() => {
            this.setState({ curTime: new Date() });
        }, 1 * 1000); // every 1 seconds
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        clearInterval(this.update);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="header_clock">
                    {this.state.curTime.toLocaleTimeString()}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="wrapper">
        <Time />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 20em;
  height: 5em;
  background-color: red;
  overflow: auto;
}

.header_clock {
  font-size: 6em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```